# How to remove default orange background from CollectionView selected item?

Tags: android, xaml, styles, maui, collectionview

This collection view is fine but after item selection. There is visible orange background. How should I remove it?

[image]

```
      <CollectionView 
                        x:Name="MyCollectionView"
 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                        Margin="10,10,0,10">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PlcGroup">

                    <Frame Margin="0,0,5,0" Padding="10,5" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="10">
                        
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroupList>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource unselectedGroup}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource selectedGroup}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateGroupList>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectItem, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}}}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        
                    </Frame>


                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>
```

It really is a pain to change style to all descendants to DataTemplate but I just want to set color to frame background. In a perfect world I would like to change label´s TextColor as well but I gave up on that.

It seems to ask this question I need to enter more text, but there is not really much more to ask.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color

Comment: Ofcourse I have read that. You can see I use Visual manager. That is not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may due to the default color of CollectionView Selected Item. I give a workaround here.

You could wrap the **Frame** in a Container, such as **StackLayout** and set the BackgroundColor property to white. Set `x:Name="myFrame"` to the Frame which we will use in VisualStateManager.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
        <Frame x:Name="myFrame" ....
```

Then VisualStateGroup should be attached to StackLayout as it is the outer container:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
        <Frame x:Name="myFrame"   Margin="0,0,5,0" Padding="10,5" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="10">              
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            ....
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />                                                                                  
        </Frame>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="myFrame" Property="Frame.Style" Value="{DynamicResource unselectedGroup}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter  TargetName="myFrame" Property="Frame.Style" Value="{StaticResource selectedGroup}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>   
    </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. Visual manager applies style for top element, then using TargetName you can set other elements and properties. This was very helpful.